# Hibernate Search Not Indexing after change one field

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Hi I am trying to solve Hibernate Search to index a column changed by classic Sql query as follows:

```
 @Override
    public boolean updateColumn(K entityId, String columnName, String columnValue) {
        String entityName = daoType.getSimpleName();
        ClassMetadata employeeMeta = currentSession().getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(daoType);
        String primaryKey = employeeMeta.getIdentifierPropertyName();
        String queryString = "update " + entityName + " set " + columnName + "='" + columnValue + "' where " + primaryKey + "=" + entityId;
        org.hibernate.Query query = currentSession().createQuery(queryString);

        boolean result = query.executeUpdate() > 0;
        return result;
    }
```

Calling above method as follows:

```
belgeSatirService.updateColumn(1, "basvuruNo", "thgm");
```

After updating "basvuruNo" column, Hibernate does not automatically update basvuruNo column. The definition of this column is below:

```
@Field(store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "BasvuruNo", length = 30)//13/95088973/0735/000001
@Analyzer(definition = "whitespaceanalyzer")
private String basvuruNo;
```

Comment: Your entity instance could be cached. Call evict() and refetch the entity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505072/hibernate-hql-query-does-not-update-the-lucene-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Search doesn't support intercepting update changes applied using a query.

I would recommend to rewrite the DAO pattern to use Hibernate friendly patterns: by using actual objects and setters on your domain model.

You'll have several other benefits from it, such as:

- make it possible to enable 2nd level caching.
- benefit from dirty checking: avoid unnecessary database connections and operations.
- high performance state processing, should you want to enable bytecode instrumentation or similar.
- Hibernate Envers, Hibernate Search, and other tools properly integrated.
- you'll also be saving loads of memory at runtime: much better performance.

A method like that would look like something like this:

```
public void updateBasvuruNo(K entityId, Class<E> type, String newBasvuruNo) {
    E yourEntity = currentSession().load( type, entityId );
    yourEntity.setBasvuruNo( newBasvuruNo );
}
```

State on managed entities is flushed to the database as needed, only if needed, and controlled by your application: normally by the transaction scope.
So you'll probably not want to use such an helper at all, it's just unnecessary boilerplate.